# Github: cannot fetch last commit with remote URL type https, but OK with ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

I pushed a commit from system A to github.com, but could not pull it on system B, getting the message "Already up-to-date.". However, when I change the remote URL using the ssh schema, I can pull the commit:

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/identinetics/saml2test2 (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/identinetics/saml2test2 (push)
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:identinetics/docker-saml2test2.git
$ git fetch
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 949, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
remote: Total 949 (delta 32), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 892
Receiving objects: 100% (949/949), 4.53 MiB | 1.57 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (282/282), done.
From github.com:identinetics/docker-saml2test2
 + 2946d92...27e6f9a master     -> origin/master  (forced update)

$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/identinetics/saml2test2 
$ git fetch
From https://github.com/identinetics/saml2test2
 + 27e6f9a...2946d92 master     -> origin/master  (forced update)
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:identinetics/docker-saml2test2.git
$ git fetch
From github.com:identinetics/docker-saml2test2
 + 2946d92...27e6f9a master     -> origin/master  (forced update)
```

I have no issue with ssh on this system, but I would like to understand the problem, because other target systems are behind firewalls that block ssh.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing two different repos, `identinetics/saml2test2` and `identinetics/docker-saml2test2`.